# Replace line in Ansible playbook

Tags: mongodb, ansible

How to replace line/path using ansible playbook yaml file

below is the sample.conf file and i want to replace the systemLog.path location to a new directory

systemLog:

```
destination: file
logAppend: true
path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

to

systemLog:

```
destination: file
logAppend: true
path: /data/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use *lineinfile* module.

```
- lineinfile:
    path: sample.conf
    regexp: '^path'
    line: 'path\: /data/log/mongodb/mongod.log'
```